# Do generic classes share static members?

Tags: java, generics, static

I would like to ask about generic classes. What happens when I create two object instance from a generic class. Do they share every static members, or both have it's own static members?

So for example:

```
public A<?>(){
    public static Integer member = 0;
}

A<Integer> integer = new A<Integer>();
A<String> string = new A<String>();
```

Do both `Integer` and `String` have the same reference behind `member`?

Comment: Your question is valid, but the code you posted is bad: It's neither a valid constructor, nor a class declaration. The answer to your question is: Yes, they share every static member. Also, you could answer the question yourself: `System.out.println(integer.member == string.member);` Which is the same as `System.out.println(A.member == A.member);` because of being `static`)

Comment: It's not difficult to test...

Comment: What happens if member itself is generic? Like `public class MyClass<T> { public static T member; }`??

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: wouldn't compile.

Comment: This is what happens when you're too lazy to just try the code...

Comment: Sorry guys, it maybe seems to be laziness, but I would like to get some hints and confirmation about the topic.

Comment: @Lucia - It is best not to "fix" the code within a *question* (even when it is obviously wrong), because it may obscure the problem that brought that person here in the first place. If you spot an error, leave a comment or post an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public class A<T>{
    public static Integer member = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      A<Integer> integer = new A<Integer>();
      A<String> string = new A<String>();

      integer.member++;
      System.out.println(string.member);
    }
}
```

Output

```
1
```

So, yes the two instances share the same `member` variable.

Comment: +1 Nice example for the question. Also noteworthy that `integer.member++;` is bad style, and stylecheckers discourage code like this. `static` members should always be accessed in a static manner, i.e.: `A.member++;`.

Comment: When you're in doubt test it! :) +1

Answer (score 3):

Good question but the anwser is: no you can't for a very simple reason: once compiled there is no such thing as A<Integer> or A<String>, only A because for **backward compatibility** reasons Java uses **generics type-erasure**.

In other languages like **C#** things would work as you expect because C# was created from start with generics.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning C#. The original of my thought came from a C# example.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation: hard to go back 10 years in the past when using Java but I'm sure it will fill the gap. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no class literal (`A<Integer>.class` or `Class` instance) that represent any of parameterized type (like `A<Integer>`).   There will always be only one for the raw version `A` (i.e. `A.class`), and that's the one with whom all the static members belong.

That's why you won't do something like `A<Integer>.member`, it should always be the raw version `A.member` (and that is the one (and only) shared by all the instances).

You can read an article on the topic here - [Is there one instances of a static field per instantiation of a generic type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ401).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they would share the variable. The rules about static class variables don't change based on the use of Generics. A static class variable is shared by all instances.

Comment: This should not be taken for granted. In C++ `A<Integer>` and `A<String>` would be different classes with distinct static data members.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti: This is a question under the `java` tag....

Comment: Indeed. Yet Java Generics were inspired by C++ templates and I think it's important to point out the differences.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti Then why is this missing in your own answer? :)

Comment: Because Simon seemed to take for granted that there was only one A class. I just wanted to point out that this might not be self-evident for the OP

Comment: ...and it didn't occur to me until after I read Simon's answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

They all share their static attributes because at runtime `A<Integer>` and `A<String>` are not distinct classes.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to think that generics are for compilation purpose. At runtime, there is no difference between `A<Integer>` and `A<String>`: they are all instances of `A`. So static members are common to any instances you can create, without any regard to the type you are using.